# How to get Spotify image from URI

Tags: spotify

I have a URI like this:

```
spotify:image:ab67616d0000b2737005885df706891a3c182a57
```

I want to know how to get the image from this URI? I'm currently using the Web API. I imagine I might need to convert the URI into the image URL some how.

I can't see anything elsewhere on Google or in the API docs. What can I try next?

Comment: Where did you get that URI from?

Comment: From the Spotify SDK, though maybe that only ever appears on the mobile SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is you can't convert between the two, but if someone comes along one day with a way to do it I'll happily mark your answer as accepted instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can, Tyler:

https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2737005885df706891a3c182a57

I tried that with a couple of images and it seems to be working.